# HTTP headers for AJAX/ denied authentication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, basic-authentication

I would like to know what is best practice with AJAX authentication process.

When authentication is valid I return HTTP header 200 with response "ok"
What HTTP header do I need to send from server if authentication is NOT valid.

1. Do I need to set HTTP header to code 500 (ERROR)
2. or leave it on 200 and implement logic which checks response variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about returning HTTP401?

You can handle in in AJAX error handler and redirect the whole page to login screen, if it's your requirement.

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    401: function() {
      alert("User not logged in");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is 401 best practice? What is your experience?

Comment: HTTP 401 means 'The request requires user authentication.' That is the HTTP code that describes your situation. And what do you mean by 'What is your experience'?

Comment: I meant what did you use most in your practice

Comment: @jmav - HTTP 401. That's why I put it as the answer... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to send a 500 error, since that implies an unexpected server-side error that is not caused by the user.

You'll want to read up on the rfc spec for status codes:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

4XX status codes are for client errors, which is where you'll want to be looking. In your case, you could use 401 if authentication failed, and 403 if that user is not allowed to view the resource.